# Which framework is best for developing the UI on the Linux Based Platform?

Tags: qt, user-interface, gtk, embedded

There are lot of UI frameworks available for developing UI for Linux Based OS on various  embedded Boards running linux.I have jotted down the few app requirements for that.

***Application Requirement :***

1>A UI depicting 4-5 tables showing dynamic values which keep on changing with time (~after very 5 secs)

2>The data can be depicted in the graphical format( a line graph or a bar graph depicting values).There will be a separate Tab for it.The Graph can also show the dynamic values getting changed - Auto refresh kind of display like in stock market applications.

3>Event based Alarm(Audible or Visible) which canbe triggered on the basis of these dynamic values, eg say if one value crosses X or is in between Y and Z the even will trigger the Alarm.

4>The Ability of the UI components to take the value from the System Layer ( like JNI interfaces in Android)

5> Ability to port it on multiple platform running linux - **Embedded Boards**

Now I have the following choices to develop the application.I am giving scores for each of the above criteria 1-5 to each one of them.(10 being the best , 1 being the least , 5 X 10 = 50 is the ideal score , but i am looking for the  average 40 value , priority is more on Graphical display capability - Point 2)

- QT
- GTK
- PyGTK
- Using Both Python and GTK
- Develop using Android UI Framework, in case if I decide to use my UI application for Android.
- C++ GUI

Can some one please tell me why I must use one and why not other.I am thinking to develop the application using the GTK as for now.
Plz assert/de-assert my decision.

Rgds,
Softy

Comment: You haven't stated which language you are better at, GUIs are complicated things, and that's going to have a large impact on the speed and ease of development.

Comment: I am good at C++ and C, python.No prior knowledge of GTK but I can learn it from the samples fast.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you which to choose, but your analysis method can be improved.  I suggest that you use the [Kepner-Tregoe Decision Analysis](http://www.decision-making-confidence.com/kepner-tregoe-decision-making.html) method.

This is essentially the same as what you have suggested except that each requirement is given a weight reflecting the importance to be placed on that factor.  That way you give each attribute a score on its own merits rather than having to factor in how important it is in relation to other attributes - the weights make that part of the process separate and independent.  Then the score for each requirement is n x weight.  The total score, and maximum possible score are then largely irrelevant, it is the relative scoring that is important.  However I suggest that you reduce the range to 0-5 for score and 1-5 for weights (a weight of zero would mean the factor is not a consideration, so would be redundant), otherwise you may find that the distinction between options is not clear.

While the allocation of weights and scores is still more-or-less subjective, the separation of merit from importance typically render the result far less subjective than if you attempt to factor both into a single score.

Comment: Well the Qs was more on The UI language usage rather than the decision of "Choosing Language" .I might have written the Qs wrongly.

Comment: Indeed; the method suggested will help you either make the decision yourself or assess any answers you might get in a more sophisticated way. It was not intended as a direct answer, but warranted more than a comment.  Given your C++ experience, you should probably consider also wxWidgets.